# Security Group and Subnet belong to different networks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am working on deploying IaC to AWS. All is well except for a perplexing issuing I am having with my deployment of EC2 instances through an ASG. When I run Terraform apply I get the following error message:

"Security Group sg-xxxxx and Subnet subnet-xxxxx belong to different networks. Launching EC2 instance failed."

Terraform is using trying to use a default subnet instead of the subnet I defined to be used with the vpc I created. I am not using an ELB at the moment only using an LC and ASG. Below are the code snippet's. Any insight would be helpful!

```
/******************************************************************
                        Subnet Definitions
*******************************************************************/

//Define the public subnet for availability zone A.
resource "aws_subnet" "Subnet_A_Public" {
    vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
    cidr_block        = "${var.public_subnet_a}"
    availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone_a}"

  tags {
      Name  = "Subnet A - Public"
  }
}

//Define the public subnet for availability zone B.
resource "aws_subnet" "Subnet_B_Public" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "${var.public_subnet_b}"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone_b}"

  tags {
      Name  = "Subnet B - Public"
  }
}

/*********************************************************************
                        Security Group (SG) Definitions
**********************************************************************/

//Define the public security group.
resource "aws_security_group" "tf-public-sg" {
    name    = "TF-Public-SG"
    description = "Allow incoming HTTP/HTTPS connections and SSH access from the Internet."
    vpc_id  = "${aws_vpc.terraform-vpc.id}"

    //Accept tcp port 80 (HTTP) from the Internet.
    ingress {
        from_port   = 80
        to_port     = 80
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    //Accept tcp port 443 (HTTPS) from the Internet.
    ingress {
        from_port   = 443
        to_port     = 443
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    //Accept tcp port 22 (SSH) from the Internet.
    ingress {
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    //Accept all ICMP inbound from the Internet.
    ingress {
        from_port   = -1
        to_port     = -1
        protocol    = "icmp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }

    tags {
        Name    = "Terraform Public SG"
    }
}

/**************************************************************************
            PUBLIC ASG & LC
***************************************************************************/
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "terraform-public-lc" {
  image_id  = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  security_groups   = ["${aws_security_group.tf-public-sg.id}"]

  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf-public-asg" {
  launch_configuration       = "${aws_launch_configuration.terraform-public-lc.id}"
  availability_zones         = ["${var.availability_zone_a}", "${var.availability_zone_b}"]
  name                       = "tf-public-asg"

  min_size                  = "${var.asg_min_pubic}"
  max_size                  = "${var.asg_max_public}"
  desired_capacity          = "${var.asg_desired_capacity_public}"

  tags {
      key                   = "Name"
      value                 = "tf-public-asg"
      //value                 = "${var.public_instance_name}-${count.index}"
      propagate_at_launch   = true
  }
}
/************************************************************************
            END PUBLIC ASG & LC
*************************************************************************/
```

Comment: You haven't specified the VPC using `vpc_zone_identifier` so it's probably trying to put the ASG in your default VPC instead of the one you've created your security group in. Can you try setting the `vpc_zone_identifier` to the subnets you've created above that?

Comment: Interestingly enough after adding the vpc_zone_identifier I don't get the error anymore. But rather I now have hit a bug in Terraform.

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

"* aws_autoscaling_group.tf-public-asg: aws_autoscaling_group.tf-public-asg: diffs didn't match during apply. This is a bug with Terraform and should be reported as a GitHub Issue."

This time it didn't even create the ASG whereas before it did.

Comment: Doing some debugging I commented out the "availability_zones" in my ASG definition and then reran "terraform apply" and the issue went away. There seems to be some sort of conflict when defining both "availability zones" and "vpc_zone_identifier". Commenting out "availability_zones" seems to be a workaround for now. Hopefully this information will help others if they run across this in their deployments. As an FYI I am running Terraform from command line and the version is: v0.11.10 + provider.aws v1.42.0

Comment: It's also specifically stated in the docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#availability_zones Not sure why they're not set to conflict in the resource definition to actually prevent that though.